# SSRS map SQL Server spatial query error: no spatial data available

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, esri

I have an Enterprise Geodatabase in SQL server.

I wanted to create a map in the report using SQL Server spatial query to retrieve the values form a table in that Enterprise Geodatabase.

For example, I want to add "TEST_POLYGON" feature class to my report. 
I can preview the Spatial results in SQL Server and the Shape field is geometry datatype. 
[SQL Server Spatial results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKFkD.png)

[data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD6Si.png)

However, when I tried to add it to my report, i got an error saying No Spatial data available. 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y6Bv.png)

What should be the spatial field data type and in what projection?
I have also tried convert the spatial field data type to geography but still get the same result.

How can I add a map to report from a table in SDE in SQL server?

Comment: That kind of looks like a point and not a polygon, trying switching it to point and add a Bing maps layer to see if it shows up correctly.

Comment: It is a polygon but looks like a big point.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/maps-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017
Under spatial data in design view:

> SQL Server spatial data. If the data source is available and the credentials are valid, the sample data is loaded from the spatial data in the database. Otherwise, the report processor generates sample data and displays the message No spatial data available.

Check your connection is working without spatial data.